# Gradle Build fails with new Gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I tried starting a new project with the new version 3 of Android Studio. I get this error message:
[image]

here is gradle.wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

root.gradle

```
   buildscript {

        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
            classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zabitoglu.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta5'
}
```

I tried resolve the issue with the invalidation of cache method, and stopping Gradle daemon, but nothing happen ..

Comment: Is the backslash next to 'https' normal?